# What is the origin of the term "yank"?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, history-of, original-vi

I'm interested in learning how the term *yank* got its name.  I'm also interested in why Vi/Vim "yank" differs from Emacs "yank".

See also: [same question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209660/why-is-the-vi-editors-copy-command-called-yank); [dual question about Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17056/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-yank)

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14632/why-does-yank-in-vim-mean-copy

Comment: In [Bill Joy's original vi reference](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper-4.html#section23), `y` is described as *"yank operator, for copies and moves"*. As mentioned in romainl's link, the reason that *yank* was chosen is probably because the `y` key was free.

Comment: Good thing the free key wasn't `w` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is **d**ragged/**m**oved/**p**ulled/**y**anked into to clipboard. It's just a synonymous found to be easy to remember the **y** key, since all other keys are used.

Comment: "d" is delete, "p" is print or put.